# Re-enable landscape orientation in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

I temporarily disabled landscape orientations in my iPhone app while I fixed a problem with an image.  Now, for the life of me, I can't get any pages to AutoRotate to either landscape orientation. It worked fine previously. I have all 4 orientations identified in the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` in the `info.plist`.  All 4 orientations are highlighted in the Targets Summary Supported Device Orientations.  My implementation files all have:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {    
    return YES;
}
```

I'm sure it's something stupid I'm missing, but I can't find it after trying for hours. Any thoughts????

Answer (score 3):

If you are certain that each viewController has

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
           return YES; 
    }
```

then you may want to try deleting the `Build/` directory, selecting `clean all targets` in the build options, and then relaunching the app. Sometimes this miraculously works. Also, closing and re-opening the simulator and/or Xcode is a common mystery solution for me.

If this doesn't work, then you may want to read through Apple's trouble shooting guide: [Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately no luck. I've spent too much time trying to get this to work again. I guess the next option if to create a new project and import in all the files?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clean all targets - the updated plist may not be getting copied into the app bundle. If this is on the device, you may try deleting the app from the device as well.